# Create this table using a single classic html table element and rowspan/colspan

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a  table that looks like this using classic HTML table constructs:

[image]

Thinking left to right I came up with the following HTML which was a disaster.  Am I missing something?

```
<html>
<body>
<table border = 1 width=640 height=480>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2>1</td>
    <td rowspan=4 colspan=4>2</td>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2>3</td>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2>4</td>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=4 colspan=4>6</td>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2>7</td>
    <td rowspan=1 colspan=1>8</td>
    <td rowspan=1 colspan=1>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=1 colspan=1>10</td>
    <td rowspan=1 colspan=1>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2>12</td>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2>13</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to use the `table` element?

Comment: It won't be possible with just one table, more like many of them and then you still will most likely need CSS to align it properly.

Comment: what did that html look like?

Comment: try making a `tr` beneath the table and 1 extra `td` each row with the length/height you want each `td`, it may work.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight: I put up a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqqcv/

Comment: you just have to fill it up, if you dont have a even amount of span, you get that kind of table.

Comment: your using `rowspan` and `colspan` incorrectly, how is the computer supposed to know when to skip, and when to stay on the same side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One table styled with CSS.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="green"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="red"></td>
    <td class="green" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="green"></td>
    <td class="green" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" class="red"></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="green"></td>
    <td class="blue"></td>
    <td class="blue"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="blue"></td>
    <td class="blue"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="green"></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="green"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-width: 8em;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.green {
  background: rgb(155,187,89);
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}
.red {
  background: rgb(192,80,77);
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
}
.blue {
  background: rgb(79,129,189);
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}
```

**Result**

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for you. I hope this becomes useful to you because I spent an hour trying to create this for you. (notice HTML 5 recommends using CSS but since you wanted this in just classic html here is the solution for you)

```
<table width="800" height="400">
        <tr width=50%>
            <td width="33%" bgcolor="#6CBB3C"></td>
            <td width="33%" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C24641" width=40%></td>
            <td width="33%" bgcolor="#6CBB3C"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr width=50%>
            <td width="33%" bgcolor="#6CBB3C"></td>

            <td width="33%" bgcolor="#6CBB3C"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>


    <table width="800" height="400">
        <tr width="50%">
            <td width="50%" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C24641" width=40%></td>
            <td width="25%" bgcolor="#6CBB3C"></td>
            <td width="25%" bgcolor="#6CBB3C" height="200pix" bgcolor="white">


                <table width="100%" height="200pix" bordercolor="white"
                    bgcolor="white">

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#7A5DC7"></td>

                        <td bgcolor="#7A5DC7"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#7A5DC7"></td>

                        <td bgcolor="#7A5DC7"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr width="50%">
            <td bgcolor="#6CBB3C"></td>

            <td bgcolor="#6CBB3C"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

here is the  result for you:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for doing that.  I was hoping to learn if it was possible to do it with a single table element and rowspan/colspan.  Multiple tables will not work in my application.  Somebody deleted the 'is it possible' from my question which worded it like a challenge.  It was really a question.  Again, thanks for the time and effort.